# How do I add a background to a scroll view and have it repeat to the end?

Tags: swift

I am making a roster on a scroll view with every slide being someone different. I was wondering if there is a way to set a background and have it repeat to the end as it cuts off at a certain person

Currently, I am copy and pasting the background and dragging it to match

for i in 0..

```
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:xPosition+110, y: 350, width: 200, height: 200))
        label.text = names[i]
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 35, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.textColor = UIColor.black


        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: names[i])
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition-110, y: 150, width: 650, height: 250)

   let descriptionM = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition+65, y: 525, width: 300, height: 250))
        descriptionM.text = desc[i]
        descriptionM.textColor = UIColor.black
        descriptionM.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        descriptionM.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        descriptionM.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)


        scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        scrollView.addSubview(label)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.addSubview(descriptionM)

    }
```

Results would be the photo to repeat to the end and past.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to turn the background image into a resizable image with zero edge insets and the default (tiling) resizing mode. Set your image view's `contentMode` to `.scaleToFill`.

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "background")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    imageView.image = image
```

Then make sure your `imageView` is at least as big as your scroll view's `contentSize`.